# String.Format number arguments - Java

Tags: java, string, android-studio, formatting, format

I've been trying to assign a string to number format with variable decimal places (depending on how man decimal places are in the string) and also want the formatting to be localized (so "12456.789" will be formatted to "123,456.789" in Europe and "123.456.789" in Southeast Asia).

The code I have below doesn't do it because I'm not sure what argument to put in to achieve this (there may be a need to assign an int value to the decimal places?)

Can a string be formatted in this way of do I first have to parse sCurrentNumber (the sting) into a double value and then pass it in?

```
sCurrentNumber = String.format(sCurrentNumber + "0");
```

Also, on the localisation - is done through the highlighted function?:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes, it needs to be parsed into a double if you want to utilize the format function. A start would be to use the grouping flag with String.format. Assuming 'currentNumber' is a double:

```
String sCurrentNumber = String.format("%,f", currentNumber);
```

Will at least get you the appropriate Locale grouping characters. However, you may have to deal with some precision details as well.

See [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) docs for more.

Comment: Thanks. I've heard about this precision problem before but not entirely sure what it's all about (I think it's clear at this stage I'm no Java programmer!) can you give me a quick summer on what it is and how it's corrected - surely 3 * 5 is always 15? (I know, poor example, but I think you get what I'm saying)

Comment: I just meant there may be trailing zeros when you format a number this way. You will have to decide how much precision you want in the formatted number. Take a look at the link I posted. I know it is a lot, but i18n for Strings is definitely not a unique problem to Java, so the concepts should hopefully be familiar.